# I have "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error

Tags: c#

i have problem when I click on button3 and button4
i haven`t idea what i do wrong 
it looks that my program try to get threadArray in position that except of index

ps my english isn`t good but i can read nice

```
    Thread[] threadArray;
    int numberThread;

    public delegate void myDelegate(int x);
    myDelegate[] myDelegates;

    int[] numberOfIterations;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        comboBox2.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        comboBox2.Enabled = false;
        comboBox3.Enabled = false;
        numericUpDown2.Enabled = false;
        comboBox3.Items.Add("product");
        comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        threadArray = new Thread[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
        numberThread = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        myDelegates = new myDelegate[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
        numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;
        numberOfIterations = new int[numberThread];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberThread; i++)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(i+1);
        }
        comboBox2.Enabled = true;
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox3.Enabled = true;
        numericUpDown2.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedItem);
        x = x - 1;
        numberOfIterations[x] = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
        if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            myDelegates[x] = null;
            myDelegates[x] += Functions.productDev;
        }
        threadArray[x] = new Thread(()=>myDelegates[x]((int)numericUpDown2.Value));
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberThread; i++)
        {
            threadArray[i].Start();
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numberThread; j++)
        {
            numberOfIterations[j] = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
            if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                myDelegates[j] = null;
                myDelegates[j] += Functions.productDev;
            }
            threadArray[j] = new Thread(() => myDelegates[j](numberOfIterations[j]));
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It means you're trying to access an array element on a position that's exceeding its length. Also, you need to explain what are you trying to achieve and where does that problem occur. Don't expect that you'll paste a wall of code and we'll start searching for your problem.

Comment: Why don't you try attaching the debugger?

Comment: button3_Click generate threadArray that lenght is equal to numberThread all element of this array have joined delegate next when i click on button4 it try to call all threadarray element and that error occurs

Comment: Could you explain the flow?

Comment: Put a break point and debug the code , and you can easily found which line throws Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that all of your arrays are initializing in `button1_Click` event. What if you did not press `Button1`. Instead initialize them in constructor.

```
public void InitValues()
{
    threadArray = new Thread[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
    numberThread = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    myDelegates = new myDelegate[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
    numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;
    numberOfIterations = new int[numberThread];
}
```

Call this function in constructor and remove this peace of code from `Button1_Click` event.

```
public Form1()
{
    //..............
    InitValues();
}
```

Comment: huh array are bad i try to rewrite program using list